# Android Studio keyboard short cut to open Android Java Source code in new tab

Tags: android-studio

When developing code it can prove useful to view the Java source code - e.g. It is particularly useful for reviewing various defined values

I know Android Studio has a keyboard short cut to open the source code related to a highlighted item, but after losing my cheat sheet I can't find the short cut I was using

Can someone please remind me of the short cut?

Google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts) does not appear to list it

Answer (score 0):

Google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts) does list the command as "Go to implementations"

Key sequence is -> Control+Alt+B

Hint: highlight the item first